# Installing ros-lunar on Solus error:"Could not detect OS"

Tags: linux, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run

```
$ rosdep update
```

I get this error

```
OsNotDetected: Could not detect OS, tried ['windows' ...
```

I've read in a different answer, that I should use `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE`

but I don't know what value to put for the OS since Solus isn't built on any other distro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280980/installing-ros-lunar-on-solus-error:%22could-not-detect-os%22/) by [ahmadjab](https://answers.ros.org/users/33440/ahmadjab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-26**:
What OS are you using?

**Comment by [ahmadjab](https://answers.ros.org/users/33440/ahmadjab/) on 2018-01-26**:
Solus linux, this is there website

[www.solus-project.com](http://www.solus-project.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> but I don't know what value to put for the OS since Solus isn't built on any other distro.

OS detection is used for (mostly) two things in ROS:

1. determining the name of packages that provide *system dependencies* (ie: libraries and headers in the C++ case, modules and scripts for Python, etc)
2. figuring out which package manager to use to install those packages

To add support for a new OS, you'll have to figure out how that OS does its package management (or, in the absence of a package concept, installs new software in general).

Ad 1: this comes down to providing mapping rules for `rosdep` *keys* to actual package names that Solus recognises. See #q215059 for some info on `rosdep` and why that is used in ROS, in addition to an example of such a mapping. You'll have to determine which packages map to which `rosdep` keys and [add those to the database](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html). After that, `rosdep` should know that `boost` maps to `libboost-devel` on Solus. It now needs to know *how* to install it, see below.

Ad 2: does Solus have a package manager? If so, how does it work? Does it use the pkg manager from another OS? If the answer is yes, `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE` could help. If not, you'll probably have to add a package manager 'plugin' to [rosdep](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep) so it can communicate with whatever Solus uses.

Concluding: `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE` can be useful, but *only* if your target OS is (relatively) similar to an already supported OS (ie: Elementary OS may use the Ubuntu supported infrastructure, as it is a derivative).

If you can't do this for Solus, you'll have to add support, as described above.

---

Edit:

> just a quick follow up question there're hundreds of packages in base.yml, therefor I was wondering if there is a list of "core" packages I should start with to get me started?

Note that the `rosdep` database that you are referring to doesn't list 'packages', but *keys*. The keys map to packages.

I don't know an easy way to recursively list the *keys* for just system dependencies that a set of ROS packages depends on, but to get a list of what would be installed on a Debian/Ubuntu system, you can use something like the following (this is essentially #q251732, but I'm using the `ros:lunar-ros-core` Docker image here because it is convenient, it should also work on a regular ROS install):

```
$ docker run -it --rm ros:lunar-ros-core \
     rosdep install \
     --simulate \
     --reinstall \
     --ignore-src \
     --from-paths /opt/ros/lunar \
     --rosdistro=lunar
```

`ros-core` is really the base ROS metapackage (see below), so replace with the image corresponding to the metapackage you'd like to target (I'd start with `core` or `base` first though).

See [REP-142](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html) for info on ROS top-level metapackages and see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for an overview of high-level ROS dependencies and required versions for specific ROS releases.

Note: some of the `python-` packages in the output come from the [ROS package repositories](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list) (such as `catkin_pkg`, `rospkg` and `rosdep`), so those will not be found in the `rosdep` db. Most can be installed from `pypi` (ie: with `pip`), but if Solus has an official package for those, use that.

---

Edit2: I'll add this variant that prints the *keys* (which might actually make more sense when looking to add support for a new OS to `rosdep`), but as I mention in my comment below, note that this does not just print a list of *system dependencies*, but includes ROS packages as well:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ros:lunar-ros-core \
     rosdep keys \
     --ignore-src \
     --from-paths /opt/ros/lunar \
     --rosdistro=lunar
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmadjab](https://answers.ros.org/users/33440/ahmadjab/) on 2018-01-27**:
thanks this answer help a lot, so I have to add support.

just a quick follow up question there're hundreds of packages in base.yml, therefor I was wondering if there is a list of "core" packages I should start with to get me started?

thank you again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-28**:\

> I don't know an easy way to recursively list the *keys* for just system dependencies [..]

Perhaps @tfoote or @Dirk Thomas can help here.

`rosdep keys .. --from-paths /opt/ros/lunar ..` also prints ROS pkg names for me.

**Comment by [ahmadjab](https://answers.ros.org/users/33440/ahmadjab/) on 2018-01-29**:
ok I think I'm on the right path now I'll try and figure thingsout from here.

thank you for the help